# dup method not working after migrating Rails 3.2 → 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, railstutorial.org, dup

After following the [Rails 4.0 supplement](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/supplement?version=3.2#top), I got to the [Some specific issues](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/supplement?version=3.2#sec-some_specific_issues) part, where Michael mentions

> One tiny change in the Micropost spec (`spec/models/micropost_spec.rb`) is a change from the `dup` method (to duplicate the user’s user-microposts) to the `to_a` method (which converts them to an array). Here is the version with `dup`:

**Rails 3.2**

```
it "should destroy associated microposts" do
  microposts = @user.microposts.dup
  @user.destroy
  microposts.should_not be_empty
  microposts.each do |micropost|
    Micropost.find_by_id(micropost.id).should be_nil
  end
end
```

**Rails 4.0**

```
it "should destroy associated microposts" do
  microposts = @user.microposts.to_a
  @user.destroy
  expect(microposts).not_to be_empty
  microposts.each do |micropost|
    expect(Micropost.where(id: micropost.id)).to be_empty
  end
end
```

He himself says he doesn't fully understand the need to change the method:

> For reasons obscure to me, the call to `dup` no longer works in Rails
>   4.0, but replacing it with `to_a` works fine.

So why doesn't `dup` work anymore?

Comment: Interestingly, after I posted this question the test was actually failing. Tried using `microposts = @user.microposts.dup.to_a` and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#general, `Model.all` now returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` rather than an `Array`.  While a `Relation` supports many of the methods that an `Array` does (e.g. `each`), it does not support `empty?`.  The `to_a` converts it to an `Array` so that the empty tests can function.